# How to manipulate shadow of window?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, shadow

For example: enlarge shadow, remove bottom shadow, ...

And I tried to override the **invalidateShadow** selector of NSWindow, but it was not invoked when window's shadow changed. I do not want to remove shadow, I want to prevent shadow from being invalidated. When is **invalidateShadow** called ?

Answer (score 0):

How about..

- make your `NSWindow` shadow-less,
- use a 2. transparent `NSWindow` with a custom `NSView`, both slightly bigger than the original window,
- set it up as child window of your *content* window,
- draw whatever shadow/adornments you deem suitable into that custom view.